# Mutable references to immutable data in Haskell

Tags: haskell, immutability, frege

I'd like to keep track of a "current" value in a succession of immutable values.
What is the best way to do that in Haskell without introducing a new reference for every new value?
Here is an example:

```
data Person = Person {name, level, topic :: String }
    deriving(Show)

dierk :: Person
dierk = Person "Dierk" "confident" "Java"

works :: Person -> String
works person = name person ++ " is " ++ level person ++ " in " ++ topic person


main _ = do
    putStrLn $ works dierk
    -- do more with "current" topic
    putStrLn $ works dierk {level= "proficient", topic="Groovy"}
    -- do more with "current" topic
    putStrLn $ works dierk {level= "dabbling", topic="Haskell"}
    -- do more with "current" topic
```

Comment: It depends. Mutability can be obtained through the `State Person` monad. If you also need to do IO on top of that, then you probably need `StateT Person IO` instead.

Comment: The State monad doesn't cut it since you only get state succession (new states with every change) but no reference to a "current" state.

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you are trying to express in this bit of  pseudocode.

Comment: What would you consider a "reference to a current state", exactly? It can't be some value `current :: Person` since that would be immutable.

Comment: You *might* be looking for something like `IORef`.

Comment: It is most likely is some kind of reference type but IO should not be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about what the question really asks for. The posted example
can be rewritten to use the `StateT Person IO` monad as follows.

```
import Control.Monad.State

data Person = Person {name, level, topic :: String }
   deriving Show

dierk :: Person
dierk = Person "Dierk" "confident" "Java"

works :: Person -> String
works person = name person ++ " is " ++ level person ++ " in " ++ topic person

main :: IO ()
main = flip evalStateT dierk $ do
   -- use the current topic
   lift . putStrLn . works =<< get
   -- change the current topic
   modify (\t -> t{level= "proficient", topic="Groovy"})
   lift . putStrLn . works =<< get
   -- change the current topic
   modify (\t -> t{level= "dabbling", topic="Haskell"})
   lift . putStrLn . works =<< get

{- Output:
Dierk is confident in Java
Dierk is proficient in Groovy
Dierk is dabbling in Haskell
-}
```

If instead a real reference type is wanted, one could use `IORef Person`, or `STRef` if in the `ST` monad. But in such case, you must be working inside some monad allowing these reference types. By comparison, `StateT Person m` works in any monad `m`.

Comment: Thanks, this is certainly a solution for my question.

Answer (score 0):

Just to wrap up and give hints to other Haskell newbies like me - here is the solution that I finally settled with. This is no pseudo-code :-) but Frege (a Haskell for the JVM) that has some minor notational differences.

```
module Person where

import frege.control.monad.State

data Person = Person {name, level, topic :: String }

derive Show Person

dierk = Person "Dierk" "confident" "Java"

works :: Person -> String
works person = person.name ++ " is " ++ person.level ++ " in " ++ person.topic

printCurrentPerson :: StateT Person IO ()
printCurrentPerson = do
    person <- StateT.get            -- independent of any particular person reference
    StateT.lift $ println $ works person

updateCurrentPerson :: Monad m => String -> String -> StateT Person m ()
updateCurrentPerson level topic = do
    StateT.modify (\person -> Person.{level= level, topic=topic} person)

usingMutableRefsToImmutableState :: Person -> IO ((),Person)
usingMutableRefsToImmutableState start =
    flip StateT.run start $ do
        printCurrentPerson
        updateCurrentPerson "proficient" "Groovy"
        printCurrentPerson
        StateT.lift $ println "-- user input could influence which selection is 'current' "
        updateCurrentPerson "dabbling" "Haskell"
        printCurrentPerson

main = do -- using the StateT transformer to work in combination with any monad (here: IO)
    (_, lastPerson) <- usingMutableRefsToImmutableState dierk
    println "-- a second round with relaying the last person"
    _ <- usingMutableRefsToImmutableState lastPerson
    return ()

{-  output
    Dierk is confident in Java
    Dierk is proficient in Groovy
    -- user input could influence which selection is 'current' 
    Dierk is dabbling in Haskell
    -- a second round with relaying the last person
    Dierk is dabbling in Haskell
    Dierk is proficient in Groovy
    -- user input could influence which selection is 'current' 
    Dierk is dabbling in Haskell
-}
```

Thank you all.